# UNABLE To SEND EMAIL from PHPMailer, No Error Given, Message was successful

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send email using PHPMailer

I have all the correct setting and the email is sent succesfully according to the CPanel Email Trace.

However, I am not receiving any emails

This only occurs if I send to Gmail (I haven't tested yahoo or any other).
If I send to my own domain, i.e. @open-plant.com.. it works fine. Email is received

I have checked GMAIL spam, trashcan, junk mail and etc... it is not going to those places.

The Email trace shows succesfull but NO email at azrinsani@gmail.com:

> ```
> vent: success success
> User: azrinsani
> Domain:   open-plant.com
> Sender:   sales@open-plant.com
> Sent Time:    Dec 2, 2015 9:25:09 AM
> Sender Host:  pa49-196-132-8.pa.vic.optusnet.com.au
> Sender IP Address:    49.196.132.8
> Authentication:   dovecot_login
> Spam Score:   0
> Recipient:    azrinsani@gmail.com
> Delivery User:    -remote-
> Delivery Domain:  
> Delivered To: azrinsani@gmail.com
> Router:   smarthost_dkim
> Transport:    remote_smtp_smart_dkim
> Out Time: Dec 2, 2015 9:25:09 AM
> ID:   1a3wAX-003r8M-GZ
> Delivery Host:    se3-syd.hostedmail.net.au
> Delivery IP Address:  103.252.152.0/24
> Size: 709 bytes
> Result:   Accepted
> ```

The following is my phpcode

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;



$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->Host = 'c1s4-2e-syd.hosting-services.net.au'; // "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" didn't worked
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$mail->Username = "sales@open-plant.com";
$mail->Password = "PASSWORDCENSORED";
$mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails
$mail->SingleTo = true; // if you want to send a same email to multiple users. multiple emails will be sent one-by-one.

$mail->From = "sales@open-plant.com";
$mail->FromName = "Open-Plant";
$mail->addAddress("azrinsani@gmail.com","User 1");

$mail->Subject = "TESTING PHPMailer";
$mail->Body = "Hi,<br /><br />This system is working perfectly.";

if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";

?>
```

Comment: If you are receiving the email at other addresses, you can be sure Google has blacklisted your server for whatever reason. Not your fault.

Comment: Google blocked my hosting server recently and I couldn't make Google recaptcha requests because of it...my hosting company had to contact them to remove the server from the blacklist.

Comment: Thanks for the replies... I don't think that's the case cause I can send the email if I run it from WAMP.... AND if it's blocked why are the email traces being successful

Comment: I see. I would test other address like yahoo and such to see if it is only gmail that is giving you an issue. Also, sometimes there is a delay. I have sent successful emails that never showed up, then 6-8 hours later, all my test emails flooded in. I wish I could help you :/

Comment: OK, it turns out that my Hosting Server was blocking the email messages. They said they had a spam filter and my email got caught. So, lesson learned= Don't trust email traces... cause  their email traces said everything was fine!

Comment: Those pesky hosting servers x) I knew it was not your script! Glad it is resolved :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved!

OK, it turns out that my Hosting Server was blocking the email messages. They said they had a spam filter and my email got caught. So, lesson learned= Don't trust email traces... cause their email traces said everything was fine!